# Get all js hrefs using regex

Tags: html, regex, jmeter

With Regular Expression Extractor of Jmeter I am trying to get all links or paths from an html document that only relate to the javascript - i.e hrefs that contain ".js" substring.
I use next regex expression, but it's get ".css" links too:

```
href="(.*?)"[^<]
```

Here is related example of an html fragment:

```
<head >
<title>TITLE</title><link data-n-head="ssr" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app.css" as="style"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app.css" as="style"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app.js" as="script"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/app.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/app.css">
```

Can you help me please with right regex that will get only ".js" links and don't get other links that contain ".css" / "svg" and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), I would rather suggest considering going for [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) instead.

[image]

More information: [CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

If you want to continue with regular expressions it should be something like `href="(.*)\.js`

Comment: Thank you, using css selectors much better and easier way to get all that i need.